# removing duplicates from a table where the value is different

Tags: mysql

I have data like this:

```
city1     | city2       | distance    
----------+-------------+----------    
kolkata   | chennai     | 250  
delhi     | mumbai      | 150  
delhi     | kolkata     | 200  
chennai   | bangalore   | 100  
chennai   | kolkata     | 250  
mumbai    | bangalore   | 150  
mumbai    | delhi       | 150
```

I want only unique records where the same distance between the same city should be omitted.

For example, here between kolkata-chennai and chennai-kolkata I want only one record.

Answer (score 2):

Try a self join delete:

```
DELETE a
FROM yourTable a 
INNER JOIN yourTable b
    ON a.city1 = b.city2 AND
       a.city2 = b.city1 AND
       a.distance = b.distance AND
       a.city1 < a.city2;
```

The first three conditions of the `ON` clause would map, e.g. `kolkata chennai 250` to `chennai kolkata 250`.  The fourth condition also requires that, arbitrarily, the first city be lexicographically less than the second city in order for a record to be targeted for deletion.  So the surviving record would then be `kolkata chennai 250`, because `kolkata` is greater than `chennai`.

Comment: While valid, I'm not sure that 'removing' has exactly the same potency as 'deleting'.